# clustering approach to identify "state-spaces" within time-series in R

Tags: r, time-series, cluster-analysis, k-means, multivariate-time-series

I am working on a problem where I have a multiple time series, each with a size of a 100 steps, each being described by a 8 variables variables. I want to identify "states" within each time series, where a state would reflect some cluster that is learned from the spatiotemporal pattern of values of the 8 variables.

So so far most options point me towards dynamic time warping `DTW`, but I am not really interested in grouping the full time series (e.g. timeseries 1, time-series 2, etc each of 100 steps* 8 variables, into a group of similar vs dissimilar timeseries), which is what approaches like dtw seem to do in my understanding.
What I really want is to find states within each timeseries. say within timeseries 1 (containing 100 steps and 8 variables), I want to find pieces of time that reflect different clusters, they might have different durations, shapes, etc.

What I have tried so far is to use `k-means` clustering for each timeseries, where I use the 8 variables as features to the kmean algorithm, and for a single timeseries I would get something like figure 1 when `k = 3` [image: Figure 1]

the lines represent the 8 variables and the shaded colors represent the k-means clusters I identified. I would then do this for all timeseries. While this seems to work for this case, I am worried about its appropriateness, specifically, becase the clusters will be biased toward the means of the variables, and the kmeans doesn't really exploit the temporal structure explicitly.

Any suggestions of whether this is okay, or other sensible approaches, that I could implement in `R` would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: This is more of a stats question that a programming question, so I have voted to migrate it to [CrossValidated](https://stats.stackexchange.com), our sister site for statistical questions. You are more likely to get a good answer over there. For what its worth, I think your approach looks fairly sensible, but it doesn't respond to dynamic changes very well, i.e. the system is still recorded as being in the same state for a while despite a sudden surge in most of the parameters, until they reach a certain threshold. Not sure how relevant this is to your analysis though.

Comment: Thanks, Allan, happy to move to cross-validated, it's just I would also like to get an implementation code in ```R``` if possible, so I wasn't sure if I should put it here or cross validated

Comment: also, you are right, the issue you point is relevant for me, as generally, it's undesirable for my purposes

Comment: Using k-means on the `diff` of your variables might be worth looking at, though could be noisy, so maybe something like a k-means of the rolling mean of the diffed variables. This would ignore absolute values though, and again this might be important. I guess we would need to know _what_ we were implementing before implementing it, which is why CrossValidated would be better.

Comment: thanks for the suggestions @AllanCameron I will move this to Crossvalidated, but those suggestions seem useful.